# Why does my <li> move around when using position:relevant on p tags within the <li>?

Tags: css, html-lists, distortion

I have a left side menu using a fixed width ***div*** with a ***ul li*** inside, also I have ***p*** tags within the ***li*** for text. When I use ***position:relative*** on the p tags my ***li*** becomes unstable ( not fixed ) For example if I highlighted the text within my ***li*** from right to left, the whole ***li*** element will move to the left. Very weird. If I remove ***position:relative*** from the ***p*** tags everything is 'fixed' like it suppose to be.

The movement of the ***li*** is not noticeable until you start highlighting the text from right to left. It becomes very noticeable on the iPad though, one swipe and its moving not just up and down (**normal**), but left to right (**not normal**).

I have the example here : http://jsfiddle.net/prNb6/

HTML

```
<div class="left">    
    <ul>      
        <li class="list">       
            <p class="title">Why</p>
            <p class="type">Does it do this?</p>      
        </li>   
    </ul>      
</div><!--end Left-->
```

CSS

```
 body, html {
     height:100%;
 }

 .left {
     width:260px;
     height:100%;
     background:#fff;
     float:left;
     overflow:scroll;
     background:yellow;
 }


 ul li  {
     display:block;
     background:#16BF14;
     height:60px;
     width:260px;
     text-decoration:none;
     position:relative;
 }

 p.title {
     position:relative;
     top:10px;
     left:10px;
 }

 p.type {
     font-size:12px;
     position:relative;
     top:10px;
     left:10px;
 }

 ul {
     margin:0;
     padding:0;
 }

li, p {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style-type:none;
}
```

Why is the ***li*** acting this way?

How will I be able to adjust the position of my p tags without ***position:relative***?

Answer (score 0):

When you position something relative it is like taking it out of the parent and sitting it on top. So the parent no longer treats it the same. Since paragraphs are display block they are taking up the whole container but with your offset it is 260px but 10px past the edge of parent, so ipad is scrolling because you have caused overflow. it may be better to just use padding on the p-tags instead like so:

```
p.title {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

or to get even spacing all around just do:

```
p.title {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `<p>` tags are larger in width than the `li` is. Due to the 10px offset you added in. It is assigning 100% width + 10px thus overflowing the li and making it move around.

Comment: Now I get it. Can I ask you how do I get my p tags to align in the same way without any distortion problems. I have always used position relevant to move elements where I wanted them exactly , but had no idea that it acted this way

Comment: If I subtract the amount of pixels used in position:relative from the parent element. Is this the correct way to do it? If I use left:20px , I would subtract 20px from the width of its parent? Is that how it works?

Comment: I suggest using padding or margin to accomplish this instead of top/left. Top/Left is more useful in position: absolute scenarios